# yml file runs over defaults

Tags: ruby, yaml

my config.yml file look like this

```
development: &development
  <<: *development
  sub1:
    sub11: "myemail@fiverr.com"
    sub12: "http://localhost"

staging:
  <<: *development
  sub1:
    sub12: "http://google.com"

production:
  <<: *development
  sub1:
    sub12: "http://youtube.com"
```

I load it like this

```
SETTINGS = YAML::load(File.open( "#{ROOT}/config/config.yml")).with_indifferent_access[ENV['RACK_ENV']] unless defined?(SETTINGS)
```

the thing is that in development env :

```
SETTINGS[:sub1][:sub12] = "http://localhost"
SETTINGS[:sub1][:sub11] = "myemail@fiverr.com"
```

and in staging env :

```
SETTINGS[:sub1][:sub12] = "http://google.com"
SETTINGS[:sub1][:sub11] = "nil"
```

it seems that if I don't define it, it's gone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have:

```yaml
staging:
  <<: *development
  sub1:
    sub12: "http://google.com"
```

you merge in the keys from the `development` map, and then set the value of the `sub1` key to a new `sub12` mapping. Note that this replaces the *entire* original `sub1` map merged from the development mapping. The mappings are *not* recursively merged.

It is equivalent to something like this in pure Ruby:

```ruby
development = {'sub1' =>
  {'sub11' => "myemail@fiverr.com", "sub12" => "http://localhost"}
}

staging = {}
staging.merge! development
staging["sub1"] = {"sub12" => "http://google.com"}
```

and is actually [implemented in pretty much this way in Psych](https://github.com/tenderlove/psych/blob/v1.3.4/lib/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb#L264) (Ruby’s Yaml library).

To fix it, you’ll need to add the anchor to the sub hash instead:

```yaml
development:
  sub1: &sub1defaults
    sub11: "myemail@fiverr.com"
    sub12: "http://localhost"

staging:
  sub1:
    <<: *sub1defaults
    sub12: "http://google.com"

production:
  sub1:
    <<: *sub1defaults
    sub12: "http://youtube.com"
```

Unfortunately, this may involve a bit more work if you have many such nested mappings in your config.